# Python TypeError: Function takes 4 arguments(2 given)

Tags: python, class, methods, typeerror, variadic-functions

I have the following 2 classes:

```
class Heuristic:
    def process(self,data,x,y): 
        return (data+x)/y

class GTS(Strategy):
    def __init__(self, method,*args): 
        self.data_method = method
        self.process_args = args

    def GTS_func(self):
        s = self.data_method(*self.process_args) # error in this line
        return s
```

I am calling these from the main module as follows:

```
data=get_data()
method= Heuristic().process
args=(data,10,40)
general = GTS(method,args) # instantiate an object of the class GTS
s = general.GTS_func()
```

So basically passing the `process()`method of Heuristic as an argument to the initializer of the GTS class. While the initialization (commented line above) works fine, on the next line I get the error saying `TypeError: process() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)` when I execute the line marked ass error in GTS declaration. Is there a different way I should be calling the function?

Comment: Did you try `GTS(method, *args)`?

Comment: Just did, and worked! thanks ! It would be great if you can also tell a little about the logic here. I am unpacking the tuple in the class method declaration (GTS_func) anyway, why do I need to unpack it while passing?

Comment: you have to unpack because you define `__init___(..., *args)` which pack it to list/tuple and later you unpack it in `data_method(*self....)`. If you use `__init__(..., args)` then you can use `GTS(method, args)`. Use `print()` to see what you have in this variables. Now program create `tuple in tuple` instead of `tuple` and sends to `data_method()`